# Vim action inside LaTeX environment

Tags: vim, latex

I would like to know how I could trigger a certain action when I'm within a certain environment when writing code/ latex using vim. For instance, suppose I'm writing tex and inside the align environment, then I'd like every equals sign I enter to be converted to &=.

What I'm thinking of now is rather cumbersome. This is pseudo code for what is in my vimrc. Here's what it looks like

```
Shortcut for environment opens start and end tag for align environment (Using imap)
The above action also initiates a counter variable, sets it to 1
If counter is 1, every equals sign I enter should be entered as an &=.
Shortcut to force counter to zero when I move out of the environment. (Using imap)
```

I would like to know if there is an easier way to get around this. This is just an example. The main idea here is for vim to have environment-awareness.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: I have edited the title to specify LaTeX, otherwise this would be a very broad question. The method of detecting a code environment will differ dramatically from language to language.

Answer (score 2):

I generally tackle this sort of problem after the fact. For instance, I write it with the normal `=` signs and then visually select it the area and use `:s/=/\&=/g`. If you want to do multiple things to the "environment" after the fact you can create a function and trigger a key to execute it. For example:

```
vnoremap <leader>la :call <SID>latexAlign()<cr>

function! s:latexAlign() range
  exe ":'<,'>s/=/\&=/g"
  " add more stuff here...
endfunction
```

However, I think your solution is better in case you go back and edit it later. The htmlcomplete file in vim handles this situation like this:

```
let stylestart = searchpair('<style\>', '', '<\/style\>', "bnW")
let styleend   = searchpair('<style\>', '', '<\/style\>', "nW")
if stylestart != 0 && styleend != 0
   if stylestart <= curline && styleend >= curline
      let start = col('.') - 1
      let b:csscompl = 1
      while start >= 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\(\k\|-\)'
         let start -= 1
      endwhile
   endif
endif
```

You can see how it uses searchpair to determine if it is inside of the `<style></style>` tags. See `:help searchpair()` for more information.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the big delay. I had a lot of work to do and got caught up.

This isn't quite what I was looking for. I don't want to change once I'm done with the code. I want it to know while I'm inside. However, I learnt a lot from your answer, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question, but I'm not sure that your suggested approach is the best way! I have attempted an answer, but this first iteration may not be perfect. I am assuming that a LaTeX environment is simply delimited by `\begin` and `\end` commands (my LaTeX is a bit rusty!).

Firstly you need a function to return the environment of the cursor position. My function below jumps to the previous `\begin` command, then jumps forward to the matching `\end` command, calculates whether the cursor is inside this region, and continues the process until a containing environment is found. It should handle nested environments. If not in a LaTeX environment, an empty string is returned.

```
function! GetTeXEnv()
    let pos = getpos('.')
    let win = winsaveview()
    let env = ''
    let carry_on = 1
    let search_ops = 'bWc'
    let b_start = line('.')
    while carry_on
        keepjumps let b_start = search('\\begin{',search_ops)
        let search_ops = 'bW'
        " Only accept a match at the cursor position on the
        " first cycle, otherwise we wouldn't go anywhere!
        let env = matchstr(getline('.'),'\\begin{\zs.\{-}\ze}')
        let env_esc = escape(env,'*')
        keepjumps let b_end = search('\\end{\s*' . env_esc . '\s*}','Wn')
        if b_start == 0
            " finished searching; stop
            let carry_on = 0
        elseif b_end > b_start && b_end < pos[1]
            " not inside this env; carry on
            let env = ''
        elseif b_end > b_start && b_end >= pos[1] && b_start <= pos[1]
            " found it; stop
            let carry_on = 0
        endif
    endwhile
    call setpos('.',pos)
    call winrestview(win)
    return env
endfunction
```

Now you can enquire the environment of the cursor using `:echo GetTeXEnv()`.

To change the behaviour of the `=` key, you need to create another function which returns `&=` in the align environment, and `=` otherwise:

```
function! TeXEquals()
    return GetTeXEnv() =~ 'align\*\?' ? "&=" : "="
endfunction
```

Then you can remap `=` in insert mode (for TeX files only)

```
autocmd FileType tex inoremap <silent> = <c-r>=TeXEquals()<CR>
```

This seems to work in my example LaTeX file. Let me know if you find any problems, or have any ideas for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "environment awareness" and if by that you mean "am I in a latex file?" you could *enable* behavior with an `autocommand`.

Vim recognizes a wealth of file types and you can make sure the file type you are editing is recognized by default by doing:

```
:echo &filetype
```

When editing a Python file, I get `python` as a result. If you need this for latex only and you get a satisfactory response from that Vim variable, you could set an `autocommand` that uses that, otherwise you can specify the extensions in it, it would look like this:

```
autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile,BufEnter *.tex, *.latex call MyFunction()
```

Where the RedPost, NewFile and Enter are some possible Vim interactions that will trigger your `MyFunction` when the file extensions end in `.text` or `.latex`

If what you really need is some code example that will do what your description states, then maybe Conner's answer is better suited.

Comment: By "environment", the poster means a particular region of a LaTeX file determined by syntax, not the filetype.